# Getting first frame of a captured video in iOS 5.0+

Tags: ios, video, frame

My app used to be able to get the first video frame using the code below - works for iOS 4.0+.  But once my device is upgraded to iOS 5.0.1, the returned image is always NULL.

```
+(UIImage *)fFirstVideoFrame:(NSString *)path
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
             initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
    UIImage *img = [mp thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 
             timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    [mp stop];
    [mp release];
    return img;
}
```

Does anyone know how to get video frames in iOS 5.0+?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why (from [`MPMoviePlayerController` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)):

> #### Behavior in iOS 4.3 and Earlier
>
> In iOS 4.3 and earlier, a new movie player was automatically prepared to play. Starting in iOS 5.0, in order to facilitate finer-grained playback control, a new movie player is not automatically prepared to play. See the discussion for the `initWithContentURL:` instance method.

The discussion says, in part:

> .. To prepare a new movie player for playback, call the `prepareToPlay` method ..
>
> To be notified when a new movie player is ready to play, register for the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` notification. You can then check load state by accessing the `loadState` property.

Once the movie is ready to play, then you can request thumbnail images from it.